# How to get this theorem numbering to work?

Tags: numbering, theorems, thmtools

I'm using the thmtools package to format my theorems.  I want theorems to be labeled like: I.1.0, which refers to the first theorem of the first section of the first chapter.  (Also, the section counter for chapter I should start at 5.)

(Sorry for the stupid question.  I am sure that the answer to it is in the documentation, but I have been poring over it for the past hour, and honestly I can't find it.)

Thanks!

Comment: According to the [`thmtools` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf), it seems like you're interested in `\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{theorem}`. However, this will start numbering the theorem as 1, not 0. Also, I don't know why "chapter I should start at 5"? Regardless, if you're after roman numerals for your chapters, `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}` does this. Otherwise, please provide more detail.

Comment: Since you don't usually get to have anything starting from 0 anywhere in LaTeX, this is not trivially possible in thmtools. Maybe what you want re: starting from 5 is not to reset the section counter at all for each chapter, i.e. (chapter, section) should behave like (part, chapter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including the explanations from the comment by Werner, I tried to figure out how a MWE would look like in your case. It is possible to set/modify the counters manually like this:

```
    \documentclass{book}

    \usepackage{thmtools}

    \declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{theorem}

    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

    \begin{document}
    \chapter{title}
    \addtocounter{section}{4}
    \section{something}
    \addtocounter{theorem}{-1}
    \begin{theorem}
        something
    \end{theorem}
    \end{document}
```

I must confess, I also find it strange that you want to start numbering with 0, but why not! :) With the line `\addtocounter{theorem}{-1}` you can force that.